# Is there a data serialization language that allows objects to be used as the name for another object?

Tags: json, data-structures, yaml, data-serialization

I have found JSON and YAML both lacking.

I wish to do something like this (in YAML):

```
nodes:
  node: "name for my node":
    - data
    - for 
    - this
    - node
```

(in JSON):

```
{"nodes":
   {"node":"name for my node": {
     ["data","for","this","node"] 
   }}
}
```

But these are both **invalid** in those data serialization languages.

Does anyone know of a data serialization language where you can use an object as the name for an object, basically? I think it's stupid that you can't do it in YAML, though I could forgive JSON since it is designed to be simple as opposed to being flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, YAML can do that. Try the complex-key syntax (see the bottom of [spec section 2.2](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395))

```
nodes:
  ? node: name for my node
  : - data
    - for
    - this
    - node
```

That's a map with a single key, used as a key. If you perhaps were after a list as the key:

```
nodes:
  ? - nodename1
    - nodename2
  : - data
    - for
    - this
    - node
```

Comment: Can you please pay more attention to the suggested edits you're reviewing? Both the "new" URLs in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2602828) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2602835) edit do not work either. Can you please check in future?